# Can I return a json object using the jquery autocomplete plugin?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a search action that returns a json response object which is basically serializing an object using json.net's lib.

My collection has a SearchResult object that has 3 properties (rowID, Title, Url).

Should I create another object instead of SearchResult to use with autocomplete plugin?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[autocomplete( url or data, [options] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) requires either a one dimensional array or a simple list of single values on separate lines from a remote source.

Locally, you won't be able to use your SearchResult directly, rather you need to create an array to pass to [autocomplete( url or data, [options] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions).

Remotely, you may provide a different source/action that returns a response that can be read by [autocomplete( url or data, [options] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) (which is, a single value on each line).